# Optimizing and improving Python code

Tags: python

```
def factors(n):
    t = []

    for i in xrange(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            t.append(i)

    return len(t)

def trignum(x):
    return sum(i for i in xrange(1+x))

for j in xrange(1,13000):
    if trignum(j) and factors(trignum(j))>=300:
        print factors(trignum(j))
        print trignum(j)
```

Above is my Python attempt for project euler question 12, it takes a long time to run, how can I improve it?

Comment: Use a different algorithm or code in C/Assembler.

Comment: I coded this is python  http://www.mathblog.dk/triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors/ and it completes on 43ms on my machine

Comment: @Trilarion: improving an _algorithm_ does not mean running it on a faster platform. It means reducing complexity.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @xtolf The ultimate benchmark is the runtime. But I fully agree that algorithmic changes are often most useful in improving code.

Answer (score 1):

You wasting a huge time recalculating the trigsum and its factors:

> if **trignum(j)** and *factors(**trignum(j)**)*>=300:
>
> ....print *factors(**trignum(j)**)*
>
> ....print **trignum(j)**

Calculate it once and assigned it a variable then use the variable:

```
for j in xrange(1,13000):
    N = trignum(j)
    F = factors(N)
    if F>=300:
        print F
        print N
```

---

Beside of that, you don't have to calculate the trigsums at every `j` summing all numbers, `N(j+1)` can be calculated based on `N(j)`: `N(j+1) = N(j)+j`.

```
N = 0
for j in xrange(1,13000):
    N += j
    F = factors(N)
    if F>=300:
        print F
        print N
```

---

In `factors(n)`, you should calculate the number of factors without creating the whole list. Also, you could stop division at the half of the number:

```
def factors(n):
    nb = 2 
    for i in xrange(2, n/2+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            n+=1
    return n
```

Comment: I forgot to vote you up, though I believe you could've made that more beautiful and pythonic by incapsulating the memoization. Anyway, (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You should estimate your algorithm's overall complexity and if you feel like it's too heavy find a better one. If you came here for a better algorithm, then edit your question. I'm only going to "optimize and improve your code" as the question demands. In addition to bigOTHER's answer, I'd recommend to rewrite your `factors` function (once again, I'm not changing anything algorithm-wise, just optimising your code, though bigOTHER suggests a valuable algorithm optimisation, i.e. basic dynamic programming)

```
def new_factors(n):
    return len([i for i in xrange(1, n+1) if not n%i])
```

If `n` is big, you can make it lazy to save memory. This will be slower, though.

```
def lazy_new_factors(n):
    return sum(not n%i for i in xrange(1, n+1))
```

Or you can go `numpy`-happy. **Update** improved NumPy-based function

```
import numpy as np

def numpy_factors(n):
    return n - np.count_nonzero(np.arange(1, n+1) % 2)
```

It's benchmark time:

```
In [37]: %timeit factors(10000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 706 µs per loop

In [38]: %timeit new_factors(10000)
The slowest run took 4.02 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 668 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit lazy_new_factors(10000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit numpy_factors(10000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 258 µs per loop
```

So, as you see, `numpy_factors` wins by a factor of ~3. Since the function has O(n) complexity this performance gain is stable with respect to input size. And the pure Python `new_factors` is a bit faster as well.

Then we can rewrite `trignum` with NumPy. BTW, `your sum(i for i in xrange(1+x))` is an excessive way to write `sum(xrange(1+x))`.

```
def mod_trignum(x):
    return sum(xrange(1+x))


def numpy_trignum(x):
    return np.sum(np.arange(x+1))
```

Benchmarks:

```
In [45]: %timeit trignum(1000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.1 µs per loop

In [46]: %timeit mod_trignum(1000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 µs per loop

In [47]: %timeit numpy_trignum(1000)
The slowest run took 130.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.88 µs per loop
```

So here we get a 10-fold performance gain with NumPy and ~4-fold gain in pure Python.

Comment: I'm okay with downvotes, though it's generally good to explain the reason.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious one: the sum of ints up to N can be written in O(1), as a single expression of N.  I won't spoil the hunt for you, but a hint: compare the surface of the triangle to the `trignum`:

```
1 x . . .
2 x x . .
3 x x x .
4 x x x x
```